# Fluid covers the floor of a container

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I know this formal definition of a fluid:

1.) It is a continuum.

2.) It cannot absorb shear stress.

But how can you explain with that, that a fluid covers under the influence of gravity the whole bottom of a container? How does it correspond with the shear stress?

Comment: Who says a fluid cannot exert a shear stress?  What about Newton's law of viscosity, and its 3D extension to a deforming fluid?

Answer (score -1):

Shear stress is a volume quality. When you apply different forces inside different layers of a continuous **solid**, there will develop forces between these two layers (so inside the volume between these layers). For a continuous fluid, no such forces can arise, so no shear stress can develop. So even though there are different forces at work when water covers the floor, there will never be shear stress present. By the very definition of a continuous liquid.

Comment: What do you mean with "volume quality"?

Comment: @hallo97 Well, shear stress is defined as the stress that occurs if you apply different forces in two separate two-dimensional layers inside the volume of the continuous liquid ( or solid or gas). The stress occurs between these layers.  So if you apply a force only on **one** two-dimensional layer (like on the boundary of the water where it touches the floor), there is no shear stress. Of course, there is also the force that will deform the water and make it stretch out, but this doesn't give rise to shear stress. And of course, for real water, this **will** give rise to shear stress.

Comment: @hallo97 So my answer is indeed confusing, as there **are** different forces inside different layers. The point is though that for ideal continuous liquids, these forces in different layers can't give rise to forces **inside** the layers. This doesn't mean though that there is a contradiction. It just means that no shear stress will develop.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Newton's law of viscosity, or of a Newtonian fluid?

Comment: @ChetMiller Is that a fluid that can absorb shear stress, like real water? Or a fluid that can get set in motion by only applying force on the surface?

Comment: All fluids, both liquids and gases, exhibit  both shear stresses and normal stresses when subjected to a velocity gradient.

Comment: @ChetMiller But the question is about (continuum ideal) fluids. These can't absorb shear stress, according to the OP. This would of course mean that when you make a cup of this fluid rotate on the side the inside will not be able to rotate. Which is the case for a superfluid. In this case, it won't prevent the fluid from covering the floor.

Comment: I don't see where you get that, in continuum mechanics, a fluid is ideal or inviscid.

Comment: @ChetMiller Well, I didn't get that, but the OP. If this would be the case then the liquid would still flow, as super cooled helium with zero viscosity (no internal shear stresses) would flow too.

Comment: Liquid water and water vapor are both viscous fluids, capable of supporting shear stresses when they are subjected to velocity gradients.

Comment: @ChetMiller Indeed. They can absorb shear stresses. But supercooled helium cannot. Maybe this is the fluid the OP refers to.